Python Arcade 2.6.17 UIInputText register UITextEvent handler
How do you register an event handler for the above.
I create one as follows:
inputText: UIInputText = UIInputText(text='5', height=18, width=100, font_size=12, text_color=color.BLACK)


But cannot figure out how to register a callback/handler that gets called whenever a user types some text into the text box

Ok, I hacked around the arcade source.
This requires the developer to override UIInputText.on_event handler;  Invoke the set callback method and then defer to the super class
One way to do this is to subclass UIInputText as follows:
RETURN_KEY: int = 13

class CommandInput(UIInputText):
    def __init__(self,
                 x: float = 0,
                 y: float = 0,
                 width: float = 100,
                 height: float = 50,
                 text: str = "",
                 font_name=('Arial',),
                 font_size: float = 12,
                 text_color: Color = (0, 0, 0, 255),
                 multiline=False,
                 size_hint=None,
                 size_hint_min=None,
                 size_hint_max=None,
                 style=None,
                 **kwargs
                 ):
        super().__init__(x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height,
                         text=text,
                         font_name=font_name, font_size=font_size, text_color=text_color,
                         multiline=multiline,
                         size_hint=size_hint,
                         size_hint_min=size_hint_min,
                         size_hint_max=size_hint_max,
                         style=style,
                         **kwargs
                         )
        self._callback: Callable = cast(Callable, None)

    def on_event(self, event: UIEvent) -> Optional[bool]:

        if self._active:
            if isinstance(event, UITextEvent):
                uiTextEvent: UITextEvent = cast(UITextEvent, event)
                self._callback(uiTextEvent.text)

        return super().on_event(event=event)

    def setTextEventCallback(self, cb: Callable):
        self._callback = cb

Assuming you do this
commandInput:       CommandInput = CommandInput(text='5', height=18, width=200, font_size=12, text_color=color.BLACK)


Here is a possible callback
   def _handleCommandInput(self, text):

        print(f'User entered: `{text}` {ord(text)=}')
        if ord(text) == RETURN_KEY:
            commandInput.text = ''


